# Colon character : in the URL getting encoded in Tomcat 7.0.75

Tags: tomcat7, url-encoding

I recently upgraded Tomcat from *v7.0.26* to *v7.0.76* for one of my webapp. The URLs that were working earlier are not getting encoded. **:** gets encoded as %3A. I tried mentioning UTF-8 in the web.xml and server.xml, but the encoding is still seen. Has anyone come across a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the tomcat changelog and trying several versions of tomcat, found that tomcat v7.0.70 has a change for this [issue](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59317). The changeset is [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/eb195bebac8239b994fa921aeedb136a93e4ccaf). This change causes the URL to be encoded when you do a getRequestURI() call.

To avoid this issue of encoding, we are using Tomcat version prior to 7.0.70.

Alternatively there is a flag `dispatchersUseEncodedPaths` which can be used to enable/disable this encoding that was introduced in tomcat v7.0.70.